# Developing for Android phones, what phone to develop to?

Tags: android, performance, platform

Meaning would it be safest in terms of speed/performance by using the HTC G1/Dream running 2.1 be the ideal platform to build to?

Also in the same vein, if I'm animating and/or timing, how to make sure all animation/performance will be the same on all phones?   I suppose I could tie animation to clock but what about other performance actions?

thanks.
-Android newbie.

Answer (score 0):

They are nearly all the same. To my mind the difference lies in the screens (size and density). Of course the processor may differ sometimes. I also use HTC G1 to develop to and havn'te encountered difficulties yet. I think ALL animation and performance will never be the same, because all the phones differ, so you will never know how it will work on slower phones.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yes I guessed as much that since G1 was first, it would be the "lowest common denominator" for platform.  So if you dev for the lowest then it would ensure to some level of comfort to run on higher cpu fones.  So my dev platform is G1 with 2.1 to ensure highest compatibility.   The only concern I have is with speed between handsets.  Going to have to make it rigidly set to the clock.